# DRY way to set (HTML5) MAXLENGTH on a TextArea via Django

Tags: django, django-forms

Given a model:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    authority   = models.CharField(max_length=500,  null=True,
    blank=True, validators=[MaxLengthValidator(500)])
```

How can I get Django to build a MAXLENGTH into the generated HTML, so users know the limit before form submit time?

```
<textarea cols="15" id="id_authority" name="authority" rows="4" MAXLENGTH=500>
```

I know I can specify it in a custom build Form (e.g. widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':15, 'maxlength':500}) ), but I'm hoping some something more DRY than repeating the number 500 in three places, and something that works even if I just use a plain model form.

Comment: Looks like the form gets built as a TextArea, yes.  It means the length gets scattered through the code though. Is there a DRY method?

Comment: I think so. I found this information here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/

Comment: You could use a auxiliary table

Comment: If you have 3 textareas in `model.py`, you can create an auxiliar(abstract) .Then you don't need to repeat 3 times

Comment: Huh?  I can't find any reference to auxiliar.

Comment: Something like this: `class aux(models.Model):authority = models.CharField(max_length=500,  null=True,
    blank=True, validators=[MaxLengthValidator(500)])`. `class Meta:
        abstract = True`. `class B (TablaAux): ...`